# Fitting equation and retrieving r squared in R

Tags: r, equation

I am trying to fit the following equation and calculate the R squared and MSE in R.

```
ln K = -2.1789 + 0.5469lnP + 0.1256lnS
```

I am a bit confused regarding the use of log and ln in R and thus, I do not know which equation is the right one.

Equation 1.

```
-2.1789 + 0.5469 * ln(mydata$P) + 0.1256 * ln(mydata$S)
```

Equation 2.

```
-2.1789 + 0.5469 * log(mydata$P) + 0.1256 * log(mydata$S)
```

question 1 : which is the right way to fit this equation in R?

question 2 : how can I retrieve the R squared and MSE?

Comment: `lm(log(K)~log(P) + log(S), mydata)` is the correct way to fit the model. Now save your model in a variable and call summary function on your saved model

Answer (score 2):

`ln(x)` (natural logarithm) is not a base R function.   Use `log(x)` for this

If you want the common logarithm, use `log10(x)` or `log(x,10)`

Comment: I'm not sure if the question was later modified, but this doesn't answer the question as it is.

Comment: @Henry, I will check this, as I had no idea about the log10().

Comment: @Suren - this is really two questions, one about logarithms and the distinction between equations 1 and 2, where R does not behave like Excel and I answered, and the other about fitting where I did not understand the question

Answer (score 2):

I assume the name of the data frame to be `df`

```
x1 <- lm("log(K) ~ log(P) + log(S)", data = df)
x2 <- summary(x1)

# R squared
x2$r.squared

# MSE
mean(x2$residuals^2)
```

From the documentation of `log()`: "log computes logarithms, by default natural logarithms...".

Comment: Quotes in the `lm` function is option.

Comment: @Chr, thank you for the reply, however I have a question. the K factor is the unknown factor that I want to calculate, so I am looking for the right equation to solve the right side of the equation. In your suggestion, where can I fit the soecific coefficients?

Comment: So, it is not a regression? If K is not given and you just plug S and P into equations with pre-defined coefficients, there is no R squared and no MSE. Both the R squared and the MSE measure how the actual K values compare to the K values predicted by the equation. Without actual K values, there is no such comparison.